# Hide the options from select

Tags: jquery, asp.net

how to hide options except one in select through JQuery.

```
 <select class="my_select_box chosen-rtl">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
```

i want to Hide the value 1 and value 2 on certain condition

Comment: What did you try? What error/s have you had?

Comment: Couldn't hurt to know how you want to choose which option stays.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `:not()` selector along with `:selected` selector and `.remove()` function to accomplish your task,

```
$('.my_select_box.chosen-rtl option:not(:selected)').remove()
```

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Thanks for correcting the typo.. :)

Answer (score 0):

For removing option using option value, you can use:

```
$('[value="2"],[value="3"]','select.my_select_box').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Note : assuming option with value="1" is not removing

```
$('.my_select_box').find('option').not('[value="1"]').remove();
```

Working [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/6hvZT/339/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:gt()`:

```
$('.my_select_box.chosen-rtl option:gt(0)').remove();
```

---

*Yet we need to know which option do you want not to be removed?*

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<script> 

$(function () { //DOM Ready

   var sel=$('select').text();// select text e.g Option 1
   var split=sel.split('Option');  // split 
   alert(split);   



});  

 </script>
```

Comment: don't use alert like a debugging tool!